# Using contribute instead of using contributing in a sentence

Tags: sentence-construction, verb-forms

I really wonder and want to learn why actually the bold word "contributing" ending with -ing form in the following sentence.
Shouldn't be like ", thus they **contribute** to enhanced productivity."?

> Available  MATLAB  features  and  packages  help 
>   programmers  to  focus  on  problem  solving  and  allow  high 
>   expressiveness  when  dealing  with  matrix  computations,  thus 
>   **contributing**  to  enhanced  productivity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The version with the *-ing* form has the same sense as your rewrite. The only difference is the syntactical relationship between two sentences.

1. Available MATLAB features [...] help programmers [...] and allow high expressiveness [...].
2. Thus they contribute to enhanced productivity.

Your version is a complete sentence, which must stand apart from the previous sentence: a period or a coordinating conjunction or a semi-colon must come between them.

However, it seems that the  author wants to make that second sentence the climax of a single longer sentence. To accomplish this he rewrites it as a subordinate clause:

- The finite (tensed) form *contribute* becomes the non-finite form *contributing*
- The subject *they* is deleted because it is understood to be the same as the subject of the ‘superordinate’ sentence in which the subordinate clause is now ‘embedded’.